# Generate a sentence from a pre defined words

Tags: c#

I'm working on a system that generates a password for a user, place a telephonic call, and speaks the password one character at a time. For example, let the password be "BlaBla123"

Now I have this basic words:

"Capitol", "Small", and "as in"

Also, I have this table:

```
//  Letter | Word     | Code    |
// --------+----------+---------|
//  a      | Alpha    |  97, 65 |
//  b      | Bravo    |  98, 66 |
//  c      | Charlie  |  99, 67 |
//  d      | Delta    | 100, 68 |
//  e      | Echo     | 101, 69 |
//  f      | Foxtrot  | 102, 70 |
//  g      | Golf     | 103, 71 |
//  h      | Hotel    | 104, 72 |
//  i      | India    | 105, 73 |
//  j      | Juliet   | 106, 74 |
//  k      | Kilo     | 107, 75 |
//  l      | Lima     | 108, 76 |
//  m      | Mike     | 109, 77 |
//  n      | November | 110, 78 |
//  o      | Oscar    | 111, 79 |
//  p      | Papa     | 112, 80 |
//  q      | Quebec   | 113, 81 |
//  r      | Romeo    | 114, 82 |
//  s      | Sierra   | 115, 83 |
//  t      | Tango    | 116, 84 |
//  u      | Uniform  | 117, 85 |
//  v      | Victor   | 118, 86 |
//  w      | Whiskey  | 119, 87 |
//  x      | X-ray    | 120, 88 |
//  y      | Yankee   | 121, 89 |
//  z      | Zulu     | 122, 90 |
//  1      | One      | 49      |
//  2      | Two      | 50      |
//  3      | Three    | 51      |
//  4      | Four     | 52      |
//  5      | Five     | 53      |
//  6      | Six      | 54      |
//  7      | Seven    | 55      |
//  8      | Eight    | 56      |
//  9      | Nine     | 57      |
//  0      | Zero     | 48      |
```

Now, I seek to make a sentences like:

"Capitol B as in Bravo"
"Small L as in Lima"
"Small A as in Alpha"
"Capitol B as in Bravo"
"Small L as in Lima"
"Small A as in Alpha"
"One"
"Two"
"Three"

Against the supposed password.

Can anyone share a thought or so as to how I store the table in memory and just ForEach a password String and get a sentence for every encountered character?

Thanks.

Comment: It's [capital](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capital_letter), not [capitol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capitol). But what have you tried?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the typo. I tried many things hoping I'll have one code heavy store and than LINQ my way with easy one-liner retrievals. No luck so far. Looking at the answers now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

Fill the dictionary like `characterLookup.Add('a', "Alpha")`, note 'ToLower' in the code example, only store the lower case letters.

A key-value store (Dictionary) is the data structure of choice because we are doing a lookup by key (in this case the letter).

```
    private Dictionary<char, string> characterLookup = new Dictionary<char, string>();

    public string[] GetSentences(string password)
    {
        string[] sentences = new string[password.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < password.Length; i++)
        {
            char currentChar = password[i];

            if (char.IsLetter(currentChar))
            {
                sentences[i] = string.Format("{0} {1} as in {2}",
                    char.IsLower(currentChar) ? "Lower" : "Upper",
                    currentChar.ToUpper(),
                    characterLookup[currentChar.ToLower()]);
            }
            else if (char.IsDigit(currentChar))
            { 
                sentences[i] = characterLookup[currentChar];
            }

        }
        return sentences;
    }
```

Comment: I require a special case for numeric. Cant have `Small` or `Capital`

Comment: Updated to reflect the change!

Answer (score 0):

One approach could be to create your class to contain the letter, word and code, something like:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public char Letter { get; set; }
    public string Word { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
}
```

Then you may define a `HashSet<MyClass>` to contain the letter something like:

```
HashSet<MyClass> letters = new HashSet<MyClass>();
letters.Add(new MyClass { Letter = 'a', Word = "alpha", Code = "123,23" });
letters.Add(new MyClass { Letter = 'b', Word = "bravo", Code = "123,23" });
letters.Add(new MyClass { Letter = 'c', Word = "charlie", Code = "123,23" });
letters.Add(new MyClass { Letter = 'd', Word = "delta", Code = "123,23" });
//.......................
```

Then you can use `StringBuilder` to build your string.

```
string password = "acd";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var val in password)
{
    if (char.IsUpper(val))
        sb.Append("Capital " + val + " as in " + Letters.Where(r => r.Letter == val).FirstOrDefault().Word + Environment.NewLine);
    else
        sb.Append("Small " + val + " as in " + Letters.Where(r => r.Letter == val).FirstOrDefault().Word + Environment.NewLine);
}

string test = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: - Lower case public properties  
- MyClass naming  
- Including the code property, it's for looking up character codes which is not necessary  
- using a list where a dictionary should be used, much faster, more logical
- using a stringbuilder, but then negating the performance improvement by concatenating strings  
- Only lower case characters can be looked up, this will fail for upper case characters

Comment: @BasBrekelmans, for public properties, I just followed the name mentioned in the OP list, plus I didn't assume that the codes were ASCII for the characters, as per StringBuilder that was just a suggestion. If the answer is not useful or wrong, it might be downvoted, but again that is my opinion

Comment: It does not meet the requirements posted by the user. (Lower and upper case characters should be supported).

Comment: @BasBrekelmans, so ? my code has a check fo Upper or Lower case ? what are you talking about ?

Comment: - It tries to lookup the upper case character, so you require either double items in the MyClass collection or ToLower in the lookup. Also FirstOrDefault() will throw a NullReferenceException which could mean anything to the caller, hard to debug.