# Execute an AsyncCodeActivity from within an AsyncCodeActivity

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation-4

I'm stuck at a point where I'm suppose to write an activity that encapsulates another pre existing activity.

The pre-existing Activity is call SaySpeech and it has some parameters. The required ones are a Connection and a Text (which it'll speak using TTS on to the connection). Its an AsyncCodeActivity.

I'm making a new activity called SayPassword and it accepts the same parameters as SaySpeech but instead of TextToSpeak, It has PasswordToSpeak. The prelude to this was: [Generate a sentence from a pre defined words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11931199/generate-a-sentence-from-a-pre-defined-words)

Now, before calling SaySpeech internally, I need to provide it with the same parameters as SayPassword received, and replace the TextToSpeak param value with generated PasswordToSpeak.

All is done except that I can't figure out how I'd start the SaySpeech activity in code internally? I need to invoke SaySpeech's BeginExecute within SayPassword's and EndExecute with SayPassword's EndExecute.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 3):

A CodeActivity doesn't let you execute child acivities, you need to use a [NativeActivity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.nativeactivity.aspx) instead. In the Execute() method you can use the [context.ScheduleActivity()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee473635.aspx) to ask the runtime to execute another activity for you.

```
public sealed class MyActivity : NativeActivity
{
    public Activity Body { get; set; }

    protected override void Execute(NativeActivityContext context)
    {
        context.ScheduleActivity(Body);
    }
}
```

Comment: My inner activity has some required arguments. I also k ow that I'll need to add the inner activity into the Cache Metadata as well. Also, I need to simply pass the arguments of parent activity to child. as parent is encapsulation the child and except one extra parameter, the parent has no requirements of its own. I'm having a hard time figuring this one out. I need to initialize the Inner activity. If I use a default public ctor, I'm forced to supply dummy values to the required args of inner activity. One parameter is string but the other is a complex type. I stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. After six hours of trials and testing, i finally got my activity running. Here is the final code:

```
public sealed class SayPassword : NativeActivity
{

    [RequiredArgument]
    public InArgument<ConnectionInfo> Connection { get; set; }
    [RequiredArgument]
    public InArgument<String> Password { get; set; }

    public InArgument<String> Language { get; set; }
    public InArgument<Int32?> Speaker { get; set; }

    #region Implementation
    private SaySpeech InnerSaySpeech { get; set; }

    private Variable<ConnectionInfo> TempConnectionInfo { get; set; }
    private Variable<String> TempUtterance { get; set; }
    private Variable<String[]> TempParameters { get; set; }
    private Variable<String> TempLanguage { get; set; }
    private Variable<Int32?> TempSpeaker { get; set; }
    #endregion

    public SayPassword()
    {
        TempConnectionInfo = new Variable<ConnectionInfo>();
        TempUtterance = new Variable<String>();
        TempParameters = new Variable<String[]>();
        TempLanguage = new Variable<String>();
        TempSpeaker = new Variable<Int32?>();

        InnerSaySpeech = new SaySpeech
        {
            Connection = new InArgument<ConnectionInfo>(TempConnectionInfo),
            Utterance = new InArgument<string>(TempUtterance),
            Parameters = new InArgument<string[]>(TempParameters),
            Language = new InArgument<string>(TempLanguage),
            Speaker = new InArgument<int?>(TempSpeaker)
        };
    }

    private String[] GetSentences(String password) {}

    private static string GetPlaceholderString(Int32 NumberOfPlaceholders) {}

    protected override void CacheMetadata(NativeActivityMetadata metadata)
    {
        base.CacheMetadata(metadata);

        metadata.AddImplementationVariable(TempConnectionInfo);
        metadata.AddImplementationVariable(TempUtterance);
        metadata.AddImplementationVariable(TempParameters);
        metadata.AddImplementationVariable(TempLanguage);
        metadata.AddImplementationVariable(TempSpeaker);

        metadata.AddImplementationChild(InnerSaySpeech);
    }

    protected override void Execute(NativeActivityContext context)
    {
        String[] SpeakablePassword = GetSentences(Password.Get(context));

        context.SetValue(TempConnectionInfo, Connection.Get(context));
        context.SetValue(TempUtterance, GetPlaceholderString(SpeakablePassword.Length));
        context.SetValue(TempParameters, SpeakablePassword);
        context.SetValue(TempLanguage, Language.Get(context));
        context.SetValue(TempSpeaker, Speaker.Get(context));

        context.ScheduleActivity(InnerSaySpeech);
    }
}
```

I needed to create middle variable for mapping the incoming arguments so that they could be passed on to the inner activity successfully.

The article [Misadventures in CacheMetadata – wrapping an inner activity, in code](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tilovell/archive/2010/02/26/misadventures-in-cachemetadata-wrapping-an-inner-activity-in-code.aspx) helped me a lot. It seems that the workflow framework is not your everyday c# code. i have a lot to learn still. hope this comes in handy for someone else.